# How to clear all session cookies in an Ionic app on Android?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, axios, session-cookies, ionic5

I'm having a weird problem in my Ionic 5 React app on Android.  The app logs in to a Drupal 8 backend and gets a JWT token for authentication.

However, after making some recent changes to my app and Drupal, the app is now getting a session cookie as well (the Drupal session cookie).  This would normally be fine, but when I log out of the app, **even though I see the session cookie get deleted from Cookies: http://localhost in Chrome on my dev machine**, when I try to log back in on the app, the app is using the Drupal session cookie, which results in an error: `{"message":"This route can only be accessed by anonymous users."}`.

Obviously, I should not be trying to log in when I am already logged in.

But my question is-- where is this "ghost" cookie?  After logging in on the app, in the Chrome Dev Tools, I can see the session cookie in **Application-> Cookies -> http://localhost**, but when I log out in the app, this cookie is deleted.  I checked all the other options under storage and there are no cookies there, either.

Even if I close the app and re-open it, when I try to log in, it is using this session cookie, but I can't figure out where that session cookie is getting stored (it's not under Cookies or Local Storage).

I can "reset" everything by uninstalling the app and then reinstalling it.  This will allow me to log in once, and I get a session cookie (which appears in Application -> Cookies-> http://localhost).  But when I log out of the app and try to log back in again, I see that axios somehow still has my session cookie (which has been cleared from Chrome Dev Tools upon logout) and so log in fails `This route can only be accessed by anonymous users`).

How can I clear this phantom cookie, or how can I at least see where the cookie is?

Here's the login code for my Ionic app:

```
export const login = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<void> => (
  axios.post(`${baseUrl}/user/login?_format=json`, {
    mail: email,
    pass: password,
  }, {
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then((response) => {
    if (response.data.access_token) {
      storageSet(jwtTokenName, response.data.access_token);
    } else {
      Promise.reject(Error('Could not fetch JWT token.'));
    }
  }));
```

**Update**

Ionic hosts the app from `http://localhost`.  In the Chrome dev tools on my desktop, under **Application -> Cookies**, normally I only see the cookies for `http://localhost`.  However, if I navigate to a page in my app that has an iframe that embeds a page from my Drupal site, I then see the session cookie for the Drupal site!  So at least I found the phantom cookie.

So now my question is, **how do I delete the session cookie, or even better, how do I prevent the session cookie from being saved in the first place?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you and you just need to clear all cookies

In Ionic project for Android we used [cordova-plugin-cookiemaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cookiemaster)

example for Angular:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';    
declare var cookieMaster;

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

    public removeUser(): void {
        cookieMaster.clearCookies(() => {}, () => {
            alert('Error');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The drupal session cookie can be cleared by calling the Drupal logout endpoint.

However, I don't even want to use the Drupal session cookie in my app; that's why I set up JWT authentication. So now I will search for a way to prevent the app from getting a session cookie in the first place.

```
export const logout = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
  await storageRemove(jwtTokenName);
  // Android needs to have Drupal logout called because Android gets a session cookie.
  // iOS does not have a session cookie so there is no need to call Drupal logout.
  // if (isPlatform('desktop') || (isPlatform('mobileweb')) || isPlatformAndroid()) {
  if (!isPlatformIOS()) {
    await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/user/logout?_format=json`, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```